Tips for slowing down 12V DC motors? Rideable cars for kids with disabilities
We are trying to figure out how to put a potentiometer or easy way for parents to slow down a 12 V electric car for children with disabilities. The car is remote controlled and button controlled (gas pedal is replaced with big easy to press button). So the parent can steer but also the child can drive this car. We believe the remote control is Bluetooth and are using this model.  Attached is a also a diagram we found online. The DC motors turn cw and ccw to move the car. We would like to find an easy method to regulate the speed. Thank you for any advice!
CAR LINK: https://www.walmart.com/ip/TOBBI-2-Seater-12V-Kids-Ride-on-Truck-Car-with-Parent-Remote-Control-LED-Lights-Music-Horn-Bluetooth-Spring-Suspension-Rocking-Rose-Red/669089807
Similar Diagram:

We are unsure how to make this simple as possible. Any help is appreciated!
Button for Gas pedal:


I've inlined the images for you so that readers don't have to view a load of pages to understand your question. Site policy is that you give attribution for images or material from other sites. Can you [edit] to include those? Thanks.

The AN6651 is a very small-scale version that is designed for tiny DC motors, such as those for cassette tape players. But it illustrates some of the behavioral complexity of what you are asking about.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Just to clarify, the slow speed is still too fast?

I expect you get good answers. If not after a week or so please flag me and I  should be able to help.

@RussellMcMahon, why not answer online? That is the purpose of the site.

Can you plug the two motors in series? It's a bit awkward, but could be the simplest solution.

Here's hoping that the car is safety and EMC approved in the first place and that it still remains approved after tweaking with it...

One electronics hack would be to find the PWM signals to the motor, cut open the traces, feed them to some multivibrator IC which cuts down the duty cycle (assuming short cycle = slower), then solder the output back onto the trace. Sprinkle TVS and freewheel diodes over it if needed.

@DrMoishePippik  Indeed :-). I could have been clearer. What I meant was that if nobody had provided an adequate answer within a week to eg comment as I'm doing here with you and I'll provide an online answer / suggestions. Life is too full and if eager capable people sol;ve the problem I don't need to :-). The subject of 'special needs' is of special interest to me which is why I commented at all.


The very simplest way to slow the car would be mechanical: change the gear ratio or pulley size on the drive motors.

If you know or can measure the maximum current drawn by the motors, use a pulse-width modulation (PWM) speed control that can handle that current. As an example, Amazon sells a PWM control stated to handle 40 amperes at 12 volts for ~US$8, but you'd nee3d to see if that meets your needs.
Two controllers are needed, one for each motor. You might need to experiment with the settings, so that motors have equal top speeds and don't cause the car to veer to one side or the other.
As @Mattman944 states, you might also need a filter across the input to the motors, if there is already PWM control. A small series inductor in  series with the motor leads, and a large electrolytic capacitor plus a small ceramic capacitor across the input would effectively isolate the two controls. If needed, perhaps 20 mH at the rated current, and 1,000 µF and 0.2 µF caps rated for 20 V or more should be ample, at most likely PWM frequencies. To see if needed, try the added control without an input filter. If odd cogging, jerky motion ensues, add the two filters.



Yes, but it probably already has a PWM controller, putting 2 in series could be tricky.

if nothing else adding all those components will make the car heavier and therefore slower.

@JasenСлаваУкраїні, cute, but this is a car that can carry a child... and chauffeur him remotely. Perhaps it needs extra weight to be homologated in its class.
